# R: comparing a column with values in another column present as list object

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I created `DF1` using a for loop or got it from someone. I want to check in `DF2` if nos values (as a list or concatenated in a string) for the corresponding dates. I come across this situation a lot of times. 
Here is the code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
DF1 <- data.frame(det = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11','2011-07-10')),nos = c("1|3","4|2|1","3|4")) %>% print
DF2 <- data.frame(det1 = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11')),no = c(1,3)) %>% print
DF1 = left_join(DF2,DF1,by=c('det1'='det')) %>%
  mutate(list_column = strsplit(nos,split = "\\|")) %>% 
  print
# DF1
# det1 no   nos
# 1 2013-02-02  1   1|3
# 2 2018-01-11  2 4|2|1
for(i_ in 1:nrow(DF1)){
  # i_ = 1
  temp = DF1[i_,]
  list_vals = temp$list_column %>% as.vector() %>% unlist() %>% as.numeric() %>% print
  DF1$present[i_] = temp$no %in% list_vals
    }
#R>DF1
#        det1 no   nos list_column present
#1 2013-02-02  1   1|3        1, 3    TRUE
#2 2018-01-11  3 4|2|1     4, 2, 1   FALSE
```

What is the best way to create another logical column that says if `no` is one of the `nos`. How to achieve what I am trying to do or better what I am trying to finally get?
  I welcome any solution `base`,`tidyverse`, or `data.table`.

**EDIT-1**

I am looking for eliminating the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
DF1[, present := as.character(no) %in% list_column[[1]], by = seq_len(nrow(DF1))][]

         det1 no   nos list_column present
1: 2013-02-02  1   1|3         1,3    TRUE
2: 2018-01-11  3 4|2|1       4,2,1   FALSE
```

**Data** (just adding as.character() in one place)

```
DF1 <- data.frame(det = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11','2011-07-10')),nos = c("1|3","4|2|1","3|4")) %>% print
DF2 <- data.frame(det1 = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11')),no = c(1,3)) %>% print
DF1 = left_join(DF2,DF1,by=c('det1'='det')) %>%
  mutate(list_column = strsplit(as.character(nos),split = "\\|"))
```

Answer (score 2):

** first part of your code **

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 <- data.frame(det = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11','2011-07-10')),nos = c("1|3","4|2|1","3|4")) %>% print
DF2 <- data.frame(det1 = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11')),no = c(1,3)) %>% print
DF1 = left_join(DF2,DF1,by=c('det1'='det')) # no need to strsplit()
```

Use `grepl` with `apply`, just one line:

```
DF1$present <- apply(DF1, 1, function(x){
  ifelse(grepl(x=x[3], pattern = paste0("(?<!\\d)", x[2], "(?!\\d)"), perl = TRUE), T, F)
})
```

Result:

```
         det1 no   nos  present
1: 2013-02-02  1   1|3  TRUE
2: 2018-01-11  3 4|2|1 FALSE
```

This solution is "portable" to `data.table` for example:

```
library(data.table)

data.table::setDT(DF1) # into data.table

DF1[, present := apply(DF1, 1, function(x){ 
  ifelse(grepl(x=x[3], pattern = paste0("(?<!\\d)", x[2], "(?!\\d)"), perl = TRUE), T, F)
})] # the := is a symbol for assignment
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` to loop through the 'list_column', check for the `length` of `intersecting` elements

```
library(tidyverse)
DF1 %>%
   mutate(present = map2(list_column, DF2$no, ~ length(intersect(.x, .y))) > 0)
#        det1 no   nos list_column present
#1 2013-02-02  1   1|3        1, 3    TRUE
#2 2018-01-11  3 4|2|1     4, 2, 1   FALSE
```

---

Or slightly more compact without anonymous function call

```
DF1 %>%
   mutate(present = lengths(map2(list_column, DF2$no, intersect)) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `grepl` to be useful in this situation.

```
DF3 = left_join(DF2, DF1, by=c('det1'='det'))
for(i in 1:nrow(DF3)){
  DF3[i, 'present'] = grepl(DF3[i,'no'], DF3[i, 'nos'])
}

> DF3
        det1 no   nos present
1 2013-02-02  1   1|3    TRUE
2 2018-01-11  3 4|2|1   FALSE
```

Data (adding in `stringsAsFactors = F`):

```
DF1 <- data.frame(det = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11','2011-07-10')),nos = c("1|3","4|2|1","3|4"), stringsAsFactors = F)
DF2 <- data.frame(det1 = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11')), no = c(1,3), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `data.table::tstrsplit`:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(DF1)[, .(no=as.integer(unlist(tstrsplit(nos, "\\|")))), by=.(det)]
setDT(DF2)[, present := FALSE][
    df1, on=c("det1"="det", "no"), present := !is.na(i.no)]
```

output:

```
         det1 no present
1: 2013-02-02  1    TRUE
2: 2018-01-11  3   FALSE
```

data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(det = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11','2011-07-10')),
    nos = c("1|3","4|2|1","3|4"))
DF2 <- data.frame(det1 = as.Date(c('2013-02-02','2018-01-11')), 
    no = as.integer(c(1,3)))
```